# Вызвов функции или процедуры

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Задача. Просмотреть таблицу/вьюху (например `V$session`) и если в ней в определенном столбце (например `action`) есть заданное значение - вывести `EST`, если нет - `No result`.

В таблице `v$session` есть значение `KTSJ Slave` в столбце `Action`.

Есть анонимный блок, он корректно работает:

```
   begin
    DECLARE
    v_action varchar2(100); 
      CURSOR session_cursor IS
        SELECT action, osuser, machine from v$session where action='KTSJ Slave';
         v_session v$session%rowtype;
    BEGIN
      OPEN session_cursor;
    FETCH session_cursor into v_session.action, v_session.osuser,v_session.machine;
         if session_cursor%found=FALSE then
           v_action:='no result';
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_action);
           else
           v_action:='EST`!`';
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_action);
      end if;
      CLOSE session_cursor;
    END;
    end;
```

Вывод : `EST`

Если подставить `v_action='BLABLA'` вывод будет `No result`.

А дальше я тупой.

Хочу запихать этот код в функцию или процедуру, чтобы при ее вызове у меня возвращалась или `EST` или `No result` и в зависимости от результата выполнять разные действия.

```
create or replace function q (v_action in varchar2) return varchar2  is

begin

begin
DECLARE
v_action varchar2(100); 
  CURSOR session_cursor IS
    SELECT action, osuser, machine from v$session where action=to_char(v_action); /*'KTSJ Slave';*/
     v_session v$session%rowtype;
BEGIN
  OPEN session_cursor;
FETCH session_cursor into v_session.action, v_session.osuser,v_session.machine;
     if session_cursor%found=TRUE then
       v_action:='Nelz9 zapuskat`';
            return v_action;
       else
                v_action:='no result';
       return v_action;
  end if;
  CLOSE session_cursor;
END;
end;

end q;
```

Например так. Но как бы я ее не вызывал, с какими бы параметрами, результат всегда `No result`.

```
begin
dbms_output.put_line (q('KTSJ SLAVE'));
end;
```

Пожалуйста, помогите тупому, как РАБОТАЮЩИЙ анонимный блок запихать в функцию и процедуру и КАК ее вызвать, чтобы результат был таким же, как и при выполнении анонимного блока. Спасибо.

Comment: У вас переменная `v_action` объявляется в блоке DECLARE и перекрывает собой параметр функции с точно таким же именем. Уберите это объявление

Answer (score 3):

Такие ошибки, в данном случае - маскирование переменной другой переменной с тем же именем, легко находятся, сделав минимальный воспроизводимый пример:

```
create or replace function q (v_action in varchar2) return varchar2  is
begin
    declare
        v_action varchar2(100); 
    begin
        return v_action;
    end;
end q;
/
select q('blah blah') ret from dual;

RET
--------
null
```

Возможное решение - использовать квалифицированные имена переменных:

```
create or replace function q (action in varchar2) return varchar2  is
begin
    <<my>> declare
        action varchar2(100); 
    begin
        if 1=0 then return my.action; end if;
    end;
    return q.action;
end q;
/
select q ('blah blah') ret from dual;

RET
----------
blah blah
```